# An item with the same key has already been added, from dictionary

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Consider making this configurable
            const string sourceFile = "testSolar.txt";

            //const string pattern = "http://10.123.9.66:80";
            //var FirstSeparatorLastNameExact = new[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
            //var SecondSeparatorLastNameExact = new[] { "qxq)" };

            string[] FirstSeparator = new string[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
            string[] SecondSeparator = new string[] { "qxq)" };

            string[] FirstSeperatorFirstName = new string[] { "nosyn_name_first_exact:(qxq" };
            string[] secondSeperatorFirstName = new string[] { "qxq)" };

            string[] nameLastBFirst = new string[] {"nosyn_name_last_b_exact:(qxq" }; 
            string[] nameLastBSecond = new string[] {"qxq)"};



            Regex re = new Regex("^(http|https)://");
            HttpWebResponse response;

            // var webClient = new WebClient();
            var times = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
            var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            //Add header so if headers are tracked, it will show it is your application rather than something ambiguous
            //webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Response-Tester-Client");

            var urlList = new List<string>();
            var listNames = new List<string>();

            var firstNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //Loop through the lines in the file to get the urls
            try
            {
                stopwatch.Start();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
                {

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //var urNewList = new List<string>();
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var columns = line.Split('\t');

                        if (columns[2] == "R")
                        {
                            var url = columns[4] + "?" + columns[5];
                            urlList.Add(url);
                            //Thread.Sleep(250);
                        }

                        var temp = line.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                        var result2 = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                        //Console.WriteLine(result2);
                        listNames.Add(result2);

                            var split = line.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            if (split.Length > 1)
                            {

                                var hallo  = (split[1].Split(')')[0]);
                                firstNames.Add(result2, hallo);
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to access the source file at {0}", sourceFile);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Stop, record and reset the stopwatch
                stopwatch.Stop();
                times.Add("FileReadTime", stopwatch.Elapsed);
                stopwatch.Reset();
            }

            //Try to connect to each url
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                try
                {
                    stopwatch.Start();

                    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                    {

                        webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Response-Tester-Client");

                        // HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        request.Method = "POST";

                        //webClient.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to connect to {0}", url);
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    //We use the counter for a friendlier url as the current ones are unwieldly
                    times.Add("Url " + counter, stopwatch.Elapsed);
                    counter++;

                    stopwatch.Reset();
                }
            }

            //Release the resources for the WebClient
            //webClient.Dispose();

            //Write the response times
            Console.WriteLine("Url " + "\t\t\t\tLast Name" + "\t\t\t first Name");
            int index = -1;

            foreach (var key in times.Keys)
            {
                if (key.Contains("Url"))
                {
                    index++;
                    var temp = firstNames.ContainsKey(listNames[index]) ? "\t\t" + listNames[index] + "\t\t" + firstNames[listNames[index]] : "\t\t" + listNames[index];
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds, temp);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

from this:

```
var hallo  = (split[1].Split(')')[0]);
firstNames.Add(result2, hallo);
```

But how to check if value is already in dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ContainsKey` method to check if the given key is already in the dictionary

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You mean this: var split = line.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            if (split.Length > 1)
                            {
                                
                                var hallo  = (split[1].Split(')')[0]);
                                if (firstNames.ContainsKey(hallo))
                                {
                                     firstNames.Add(result2, hallo);
                                }
                               
                            }